# How to create multiple instances of some exported Axios instance?

Tags: javascript, singleton, axios, multiple-instances

I would like to crate some multiple instances from some class or React component from a javascript file:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://someApp.firebaseio.com/',
});


export default instance;
```

The thing is, I am importing that file in some other files, e.g:

```
import axios from '../../axios-someApp';
```

My question now is, will this instance always be a singleton, and be the same across all files where I import this file again? Or will there be created multiple individual instances of this component? I don't know this pattern and how this works in general with JavaScript's module environment.

and what if I do:

```
export default instance();
```

will this result in individual instances of the class?

Comment: export a `function` that returns the new instance. after importing, all the imported function to get a new instance.

Comment: what do you mean by "all the imported function to get a new instance"?

Comment: He means "**call** the imported function".

Comment: ok thanks for that.